# Windows authentication with PHP on IIS

Tags: php, iis-7, active-directory

I'm Working on an Intranet application that is build in PHP on IIS. I want to authenticate against an AD by passing the username automatically from the browser to the IIS using windows authentication. Is there anyway to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, IIS supports integrated Windows authentication.  Access the 'Authentication' option for your website...

[image: IIS1]

...and change the 'Windows Authentication' item to 'enabled' (and perhaps 'Anonymous Authentication' to 'disabled' if you want to force users to authenticate)...

[image: IIS2]

More details are available on [Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc754628%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).

In PHP the username should be populated in the `$_SERVER` superglobal.  I think as `AUTH_USER`, but I can't confirm that right now.  Use `var_dump($_SERVER);` to find the correct key.

Comment: Thanks a lot @timclutton, you saved my life, just one more question is it possible to pass the username instead of typing the name and the password?

Comment: @ShirkoShwan That should happen automatically in IE and Chrome. For IE you might need to enable a preference: `Internet Options > Advanced > Enable Integrated Windows Authentication`. And you might have to add the server to either the `Local Intranet` or `Trusted Sites` group in `Internet Options > Security`.

Comment: IIS does not support HTTP/2 when using Windows Authentication (NTLM). So is there a way to still authenticate to AD from PHP on IIS, without using NTLM and breaking HTTP/2 and giving up the speed?

Comment: @TampaCraig I haven't used IIS in years. Perhaps a third-party library like [adLDAP](https://github.com/adldap/adLDAP) (although that no longer seems to be under active development) would work for you.